# unique keyword in php which replace with defined variable

Tags: php, preg-replace, deprecated

i want a function in php which replace some unique word with defined value.
i.e

```
define("URL","http://example.com");
define("WEBSITE","Stackoverflow");
$string = "This is a dummy text with {URL} & name of website {WEBSITE}";
```

now i want the output as:
This is a dummy text with http://example.com & name of website Stackoverflow.

i have function which work fine with PHP 5.4

```
define("URL","http://example.com");
define("WEBSITE","Stackoverflow");
function magicKeyword($data) {
$URL = URL;
$SITENAME = WEBSITE;
return preg_replace('/\{([A-Z]+)\}/e', "$$1", $data);
}
```

but in php 5.5 they deprecated The /e modifier.

Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead

Now please help me.

Comment: Try with `str_replace`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback function is used like this:

```
define("URL","http://example.com");
define("WEBSITE","Stackoverflow");

$string = "This is a dummy text with {URL} & name of website {WEBSITE}";

function magicKeyword($data) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/\{([A-Z]+)\}/', "magicKeywordCallback", $data);
}

function magicKeywordCallback($matches) {
    if (defined($matches[1]))
        return constant($matches[1]);
    // otherwise return the found word unmodified.
    return $matches[0];
}

$result = magicKeyword($string);
var_dump($result);
```

Result:

> string(76) "This is a dummy text with http://example.com & name of website Stackoverflow"

Comment: OMG. its easy and short. thanks a lot Gerald Schneider. Thank you sooo much.

Answer (score 1):

Why you not simply return `$string` from function

```
define("URL","http://example.com");
define("WEBSITE","Stackoverflow");
function magicKeyword() {
  $URL = URL;
  $SITENAME = WEBSITE;
  $string = "This is a dummy text with $URL & name of website $SITENAME";
  return $string;
}
echo magicKeyword(); //This is a dummy text with http://example.com & name of website Stackoverflow
```

or with `str_replace()`

```
define("URL","http://example.com");
define("WEBSITE","Stackoverflow");
$string = "This is a dummy text with {URL} & name of website {WEBSITE}";
function magicKeyword($string) {
$URL = URL;
$SITENAME = WEBSITE;
$string = str_replace(array('{URL}', '{WEBSITE}'), array($URL, $SITENAME), $string);
return $string;
}
echo magicKeyword($string);
```

Comment: you need a loop for array